# Imposing symmetry conditions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symmetry

I have functions with some symmetry properties, how I have to impose the corresponding conditions within Mathematica, in order to perform all simplifications automatically?
`f4` - fully antisymmetric, while `f2` satisfies the commutation relation:

```
f2[i2p,j1]+f2[j1,i2p]==KroneckerDelta[j1,i2p];
```

Also each term in the following expressions has to change its sign under permutation `i1` with `i2` or `j1` with `j2`. For example, we have

```
f2[i1,j2]f2[i1p,i2]f2[i2p,j1]-f2[i1p,i1]f2[i2,j2]f2[i2p,j1]
-f2[i1,j1] f2[i1p, i2] f2[i2p, j2] +f2[i1p, i1] f2[i2, j1] f2[i2p, j2] == 
  4 f2[i1, j2] f2[i1p, i2] f2[i2p, j1];
```

and

```
f2[i2p, j2]f4[i1p,i1,i2,j1] -f2[j2,i2p]f4[i1,i1p,i2,j1]
==(f2[i2p,j2]+f2[j2,i2p])f4[i1p, i1, i2, j1];

f2[i2,i1p]f4[i2p,i1,j2,j1]-f2[i1,i1p]f4[i2p,i2,j2,j1]
==2*f2[i2, i1p] f4[i2p, i1, j2, j1];
```

Comment: The definition of an antisymmetric function of two variable is `f [x_,y_]/;Not[OrderedQ[{x,y}]] :=−f [y,x]`. Taken from [Grozin](https://books.google.it/books?id=edXBBAAAQBAJ&dq=grozin+mathematica&hl=it&source=gbs_navlinks_s) pag. 39

Comment: The following upvalue seem to work `f2[x_,y_]+f2[y_,x_]^:=KroneckerDelta[x,y]`